# Open new browser tab from Streamlit tab sending html code

Tags: streamlit

Is there a way from streamlit when clicking on a column in a data_editor (or dataframe) to open another browser tab, but just to display an html page?  Here would be the pseudo code:

```
on_click:
    html="<html>hi</html>"
    webbrowser.open_new_tab_and_render(html)
```